# What is the difference between the Hasselblad CFV and CFV II digital backs?

Tags: digital

I am evaluating the opportunity to purchase a CFV I and I am having trouble finding documentation on it which would allow me to compare to the published documentation for the CFV II at:

http://www.hasselbladusa.com/products/digital-backs/discontinued-products/cfv-ii.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B&H have some [tech specs](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/437384-REG/Hasselblad_70320515_CFV_Digital_Camera_Back.html) available.

Retrevo has a [user manual](http://www.retrevo.com/support/Hasselblad-CFV-Digital-Cameras-manual/id/523ci359/t/2/) for the HB CFV dated 2006.

The CFV introduced me to digital medium format.

EDIT: I just found a [forum](http://forum.getdpi.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1666) discussing the difference.

Comment: This was an exceptionally helpful answer, Stonjie. Thank you for telling me EXACTLY what I needed to know!